# Sed with random string inside search

Tags: linux, shell, sed

Hi everybody i try to create a script which modify string inside html files.

I want to edit this line:

```
<a class="ABC" href=/photos/albums">
```

I want replace "ABC" by "test" - the problem is that the name of the class is not always ABC it can change by a random name but there is always href=/photos...

Is it possible to replace the random name of class by test?

Thans for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through GNU [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html),

```
$ sed -r 's~(<a\s*class=")([^"]*)("\s*href=/photos)~\1test\3~g' file
<a class="test" href=/photos/albums">
```

Changed the sed delimiter only because of forward slashes in your input.

Comment: Thank you it works fine! What if i have <a class="ABC" href=/photos/album1544788"> An album with a random number?

Comment: `sed -r 's~(<a\s*class=")([^"]*)("\s*href=/photos/album[0-9]+)~\1test\3~g' file`